# Is this multithreaded Singleton more efficient?

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I have a high-throughput Singleton in a multithreaded environment. Usually I'd do something like this:

```
public static Foo GetInstance()
{
    lock (Foo._syncLock)
    {
        if (Foo._instance == null)
            Foo._instance = new Foo();
        return Foo._instance;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if doing the following instead would be more efficient since it would avoid the continual thread locking, or are there hidden problems with it?

```
public static Foo GetInstance()
{
    if (Foo._instance != null)
        return Foo._instance;
    lock (Foo._syncLock)
    {
        if (Foo._instance == null)
            Foo._instance = new Foo();
        return Foo._instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do better: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Nice link, I'm reading it over.

Comment: Nobody could say if your given code is thread-safe or not without seeing the definition of `_instance`.

Comment: @Voo Assume the instance is thread-safe. I'm interested here only in making sure the instantiation is thread-safe, ie: I only instantiate once.

Comment: If it's just `static Foo _instance;` then no it's not thread-safe because you have the wrong visibility guarantees. Has to be volatile or you have to introduce the correct memory barriers yourself.

Comment: @Voo - Very well-said.

Comment: @Voo `lock` introduces a memory barrier.

Comment: @Scott It does indeed. But `if (Foo._instance != null) return Foo._instance;` doesn't have one.

Comment: @Voo It also has race conditions even if there is a memory barrier, so that code is bad for a number of reasons.

Comment: @Servy No it doesn't if you have the right memory barriers. This is the standard double-checked locking paradigm, the literature out there about this for Java is.. extensive to say the least.

Comment: @Voo One can pass the null check, then stop, then another thread can pass the null check, then they both create a new instance, and then you now have two different instances of your singleton.

Comment: @Servy T1 passes null check acquires lock, stops. T2 passes null check waits at lock. T1 finishes initialization, releases lock. T2 acquires lock sees that instance exists, doesn't initialize anything.

Comment: @Voo You just said you were talking about an example that doesn't use locks.  Now you're talking about using locks, so clearly it's not a lock-free example, now is it.

Comment: @Servy No I didn't. I never actually used the words "lock-free" anywhere here and both examples presented here do use locks. I said that you have to have the right visibility guarantees for the second example to work which depends on the definition of `_instance`, since the first if-check doesn't acquire the lock and therefore doesn't get the visibility guarantees from the lock.

Comment: @Voo "lock introduces a memory barrier." -Scott "But [...] doesn't have one." -You  So you're saying it doesn't have a lock.

Comment: @Servy That was in context of talking about the second example where the shown code snippet (copied from the given code) doesn't acquire the lock, so saying "lock introduces a memory barrier" is correct but not enough for it.

Comment: @Voo There is no need to use `volatile` or introduce a memory barrier in that case, because of the existence of the `lock`.  The instance only ever changes from `null` to a new instance once, so if a thread is reading a stale value outside of the `lock` the worst case is it'll go inside of the lock, have the memory barrier applied, do the check again, and do the right thing, so in the unlikely event that all of these things come to pass, we have to do a null check a second time, but everything is still acted on properly, hence there is no need for `volatile`.

Comment: @Servy No that's wrong. There's no guarantee that `new Foo()` isn't inlined and an only partially constructed object is assigned to `_instance`. Which means it's possible for another thread to see `_instance != null` but get an only partially constructed object. Yes you can't create two instances, but this is certainly also a bug. It's *the* classic problem of why the JMM had to be changed.

Comment: @Voo Well, in any case [you really shouldn't be using either of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688748/is-this-multithreaded-singleton-more-efficient?noredirect=1#comment30983459_20688846), precisely so that you don't have to concern yourselves with issues like this.

Comment: @Voo: though the documented memory model does not say that the end of the ctor introduces a memory barrier, in practice implementations of .NET do give you this property. You can assume that you will not see a partially constructed object on another thread.

Comment: @Eric Interesting, so does the implementation just introduce an (implicit) memory barrier in all cases at the end of a constructor (seems a bit inefficient for something that's not guaranteed by the standard) or is there something more involved going on?

Comment: @Voo: I do not know. I'd address that question to someone like Joe Duffy or Grant Morrison.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm wondering if doing the following instead would be more efficient since it would avoid the continual thread locking, or are there hidden problems with it?

Your question is "would there be a performance gain by going to a dangerous low-lock pattern?" That is **the completely wrong question to ask**.  Never reason this way! That way lies wasted time, wasted effort, and crazy, impossible-to-debug bugs.

The correct question is **"Do my measurements strongly indicate I have a performance problem to begin with?**".

If the answer is "no" then you're done.

Only if the answer is "yes" should you ask the next question, which is "**Can I eliminate my performance problem by eliminating contention on the lock?**"

If the answer is "yes" then eliminate contention on the lock and go back to the first question.

Only if the answer is "no" should you then ask the next question, which is "**Will going to a low-lock solution give acceptable performance**?"

Note that for the answer to this question to be "yes" you must be in a situation where the ten-nanosecond penalty imposed by the uncontended lock is the gating factor on your performance. **Very few people are in a position where ten or twenty nanoseconds is too long.**

In the incredibly unlikely event that the answer is "yes", you should go on to the next question, which is "**Does a correct implementation of double-checked locking eliminate my performance problem?**"

If double-checked locking isn't fast enough then implementing it is a non-starter. You'll have to solve your problem some other way.

Only if the answer to that question is "yes" should you implement double-checked locking.

Now let's come to your actual question:

> are there hidden problems with it?

Your implementation is correct. However, the moment you stray from the blessed pattern, all bets are off. For example:

```
static object sync = new object();
static bool b = false;
static int x = 0;
static int GetIt()
{
  if (!b)
  {
    lock(sync)
    {
      if (!b)
      {
        b = true;
        x = ExpensiveComputation();
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

That looks correct, right? But it is not correct!  Consider the low-lock path. Since there is no barrier on this path, the value of x can be pre-fetched as zero on one thread, and then another thread can run and set b to true and x to 123, and then the original thread can fetch b, get true, and return the pre-fetched x.

So what are the solutions? In my preference order they are:

- Don't be lazy. Initialize the static field once and be done with it.
- Use the blessed lazy singleton pattern documented on Jon Skeet's web site.
- Use `Lazy<T>`.
- Use single-checked locking.
- If you don't care whether the singleton is in rare situations created twice and one is discarded, use `InterlockedCompareExchange`.
- Use a blessed double-checked locking pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I'm initializing the static field with the single instance. I appreciate the thorough details in your answer too.

Comment: @Eric: You have forgot to set b to true which would lead to another race condition? When b is set to true you should still be able to fetch an x which is null when your thread is reading from two different cache lines. At least on my Core I7 I cannot get this to fail. Are you talking about non x86 memory models like ARM?

Comment: @AloisKraus: I fixed the typo, thanks. The broken pattern given here does not fail on x86 because of the strong memory model guarantees of x86.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Avoiding locks is always a good idea!  But... the normal way would be:</del>

**Original Code:**

```
if(_instance == null)
  lock(_syncRoot)
    if(_instance == null)
      _instance = new Foo();

return _instance;
```

<del>This way you verify before and after the lock to ensure that you don't introduce a race condition.</del>

The idea is that after the lock releases, a separate thread might have initialized the object.  So you should check again.

**Remarks**

<del>If you read enough about this subject, you will find that most push against using `Singleton` structures in a `parallel` manner.</del>

**Edit**

Per the comments: The better method would be to allow the framework instantiate a static member.  If I understand correctly, this will remove the need for any kind of `locking`.

```
private static Foo _instance = new Foo();
```

However, as Eric pointed out... In cases where very few threads will access the object at once, avoiding locks is not necessary.

Comment: Normal?  How is this normal?  `private static Foo instance = new Foo();` is shorter, easier to understand, more efficient, and the more common practice.

Comment: @Servy The normal way for lazy initialization rather obviously. That said, the code is potentially broken..

Comment: @Voo What I just described *is* lazy initialization.  Static fields are not initialized until the classes are used.

Comment: Couldn't that be dangerous if multiple threads accessed the class at the same time?  Or does the framework somehow protect you?

Comment: Yes the framework protect you and yes it's lazy to some degree, but it's not as lazy as the given code because there are many reasons why the classloader may load a class.

Comment: @Andrew Static constructors and static property initiation only happens on the first thread that uses a reference to the class (static or non static), the other threads wait till the static variables are instantiated.

Comment: That's interesting... I wasn't aware it would prevent multiple instantiations.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. Avoiding locks via low-lock code paths is almost always a bad idea! The moment you depart from a blessed pattern you are off in the weeds and face all manner of crazy race conditions on weak memory models. **Never use a low-lock solution without a compelling performance-based reason**.  Uncontended locks cost on the order of a dozen nanoseconds.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree... But I always like the idea of avoiding `locks`.  However, I'm willing to contend that you're right (as usual) for patterns that don't have threads bumping into each other, this is a unnecessary.